# Sympy plotting in the jupyter notebook with inline backend

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, sympy

I can modify a `plot = sympy.plot(..., show=False)` object modifying
the attributes of `plot` and later invoking `plot.show()`.

If I need to customize some aspects of the plot not directly exposed
by `plot`, e.g., the size of the axes'labels, I can access the
Matplotlib backend of my plot, `be = plot._backend` with the condition
that I had already *showed* (as in `plot.show()`) my plot.

This work nicely in a terminal IPython session (using the
`%matplotlib` magic) because the figure is constantly updated and
works (not so nicely) in a script, because for various reasons all I
can do, but tipically is good enough, is to use the `savefig` method
of the backend, `be.fig.savefig(...)`.

Enter the Jupiter notebook. For performance reasons I prefer to use
the magic `%matplotlib inline`, so if I want to access the Matplotlib
backend I have to instantiate the plot in the output cell, but later
any modification I put in place is lost because the plot is no more
updated... again, all I can do is a `savefig`. If I try to do

```
be.fig.show()
```

I receive an error message

> `/home/boffi/lib/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py:459: UserWarning:`
>   `matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure`
>   `"matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend, "`

Is it possible to do what I'd like to do, i.e., modifying the details of a
Sympy's plot using its Matplotlib backend inside of a Jupyter notebook and
using the `%matplotlib inline` magic?

Comment: `sympy` does not have any `plot` function. Do you mean `sympy.plotting.plot()`?

Comment: I corrected the misspelling --- but `sympy` is in the tags, isn't it?.  What I want to modify in the plot is something that, not being exposed by the `plot` obiect, I have to access using the `plot` backend.  The size of the axis labels is the itch that I'm currently scratching but i feel that here the problem is more general — I may be wrong…

Comment: `import sympy` imports a good deal of names from Sympy sub-modules, `sympy.plot is sympy.plotting.plot` value is `True`, yes I mean `sympy.plotting.plot`.  `sympy.plotting.plot(...)` returns an object of type `sympy.plotting.Plot` that, in the body of my question, is referred as `plot`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sympy plot is a matplotlib plot. 
Now it surely depends on what you want to do. For most stilistic adaptions you may just set the respective [rcParams](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) before plotting.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["xtick.labelsize"] = 16
plt.rcParams["xtick.color"] = "red"

from sympy import symbols
from sympy.plotting import plot
x = symbols('x')

p = plot(x**2, (x, -5, 5))
```

[image]

In addition it should indeed be possible to modify the figure and axes after creating the figure.

```
fig = p._backend.fig
ax = fig.axes[0]
ax.set_xticks([-4,4])
for i, label in enumerate(ax.get_yticklabels()):
    label.set_rotation(i*15)
    label.set_size(15)
    label.set_color((1.-i/10.,0,i/10.))
fig
```

[image]

It may be worth noting that `fig.show()` is not supposed to work at all in the inline backend.